# Recreation of murderball in TF2?

Tags: team-fortress-2

Has anybody seen or played in any murderball style maps in TF2?  I remember this quite fondly from the TFC days, but for some reason it never really seemed to catch on with the community.  I always thought it really fun, and wish that it could get a TF2 makeover.

For those of you who don't remember or haven't seen it, here's a really good page that has lots of screens and descriptions of the map/play style itself: [Murderball @ TFC](http://www.combatgold1.co.uk/misc/murderball-tfc/)

If anybody can attest to it being alive and well, please let me know!

Comment: Sorry for the close vote. I read this the first time, and got a very wrong impression of what was being asked. I'd take it back if I could.

Comment: What was unclear?  I can edit if it would help.

Comment: I just got the impression that you've been playing murderball in TF2 as well as TFC - and just wanted a reaction from other people about it. I think your wording is probably fine - it's just early in the morning for me.

Comment: Cant honestly say I've seen any TF2 maps, though I'm with you in that I miss the TFC maps that did exist. I'm not sure how balanced it would be with the current weapon/game mechanics however, compared to the original TFC setup.

Comment: i would imagine that it could be balanced properly...i would imagine that the rooms would once again be sentry nests and covered in sticky bombs...personally i think it'd be fun

hmm, maybe i should go fire up a map maker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I personally haven't seen any servers hosting Murderball, but then again I've never really looked. Have you ever been to FPSBANANA? They have some maps under [TF2 Misc/Other](http://www.fpsbanana.com/maps/search?search=murderball) tagged as Murderball. Maybe you could start there and see if any ported over the functionality into a map. Otherwise try this [Google search](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&client=firefox-a&hs=lan&rls=org.mozilla%3Aen-US%3Aofficial&q=site%3Agame-monitor.com+murderball+team+fortress+2&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=) which returned some TF2 Murderball servers.

Comment: not seeing any active servers...but i'll keep looking...thanks for the links!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a Murderball for TF2: Murderball 2010! :) I have a 24/7 dedicated server running te latest version (mapname: murderball_2010_[version]. No capture points like other remakes, but a real soccerball you have to grab and hold to score team points.

Comment: @Messiah: do you have active players on your server?